# PATH variable recently changed

Tags: ubuntu, path

```
$ loopy
Command 'loopy' is available in '/usr/games/loopy'
The command could not be located because '/usr/games' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
loopy: command not found
```

Every answer I've found just says to add it to my .profile... but this should be be in the PATH for all users, and was up until recently (I have no idea what would have caused it to change).

How can I solve this on my system for all users?  What could have caused this to change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu the path variable is stored in /etc/enviorment

Answer (score 2):

See this post: http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm

Basically, modify /etc/profile